# Push Data on Parse Cloud using Background service in android

Tags: parse-platform, user-input, background-process

Write a background service which extract various device information like current user, latitude, longitude, GPS Status and Internet Status. I am able to extract all these information and seen in Log. But when i tried to put all these information to the current user object on parse cloud using "put" command i am not able to do that. Please find below small code snippet for your reference. Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks

```
 ParseUser currUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

 Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(isGPSEnabled));
 Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(latitude));
 Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(longitude));

 String username = currUser.getUsername();
 Log.d(TAG, username);
 currUser.put("Latitude",String.valueOf(latitude));
 currUser.put("Longitude",String.valueOf(longitude));
 currUser.put("isGPSEnabled",String.valueOf(isGPSEnabled));
```

Comment: You need to clarify the issue and what you've tried to solve it. What are you trying to achieve? What is your desired outcome and how does this code not produce that outcome? Why are you "not able" to use the `put()` method? Are there errors? Are there undesirable effects?

Comment: Our aim is to send the locally obtained lattitude and longitude values from background service running on a mobile to Parse cloud using put command. The problem that we are facing is that there are no warning and errors shown in Logcat but still the values cant be send to Parse cloud. So we wanted to know are the commands different for background service as compared to app or there is any other way?

Comment: @drschultz. Please tell me if i till not able to clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For future if someone face this issue please add below line.

currUser.saveInBackground();